# $http Response always keep last response

Tags: angularjs

first, I would like to thank all the contributors of this site. They saved thousands of hours of my time :)

Then, I have now a problem that I cannot solve myself. However, I have searched in the site since this morning without any success.

Let me explain.
I'm using AngularJS and make an $http request this way :

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: myurl/*an asmx file*/,
            headers: {
                      "Cache-Control" : "no-cache",
                      "Authorization": "Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==",
                      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost)
    };
    $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

The query is well executed and the object response.data returns me something. If I execute the query once there is no problem BUT if I execute it a second time the query, the response.data object will have the result of the query just perform (the second execution) AND the result of the first execution. Is there something like a cache in the response ?

What do I do wrong ?

**EDIT (as requested by JB Nizet)**: Here are the two responses :

First, the query returns me something -> OK

```
{"d":"{\"recordset\":[{\"ColA\":\"TEST\",\"ColA\":\"XXXXXX\",\"ColA\":\"ZZZZZZ\",\"ColA\":\"OOOOOO\",\"ColA\":\"LLLLLLL\",\"ColA\":\"\",\"ColA\":\"\",\"ColA\":\"\"}]}"}
```

Second, it keeps returning me the same results whereas thsi second execution should return no result (so empty response I guess):

```
{"d":"{\"recordset\":[{\"ColA\":\"TEST\",\"ColA\":\"XXXXXX\",\"ColA\":\"ZZZZZZ\",\"ColA\":\"OOOOOO\",\"ColA\":\"LLLLLLL\",\"ColA\":\"\",\"ColA\":\"\",\"ColA\":\"\"}]}"}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Jérémie.

Comment: What do you mean by "and the result of the first execution"? Do you mean that instead of receiving a single JSON object, you receive an JSON array containing two objects. If that's the case, then it's the backend doing it, not Angular. Post the two responses you get.

Comment: Note you don't need to stringify the data yourself...`$http` already does it for you. Otherwise not clear what issue is

Comment: JB Nizet> I just edited the post. And yes I get a JSON array with two objects. Maybe I should mention that the JSON in the response is a JSON I built myself in the code behind (the url).

Comment: Is the time of these calls very close together? There's a chance the first call is still pending when you make the second call. When you go to make the first call you instead get the result of the second on. Also, can you look in your developer tools when you make these calls and see you two calls are actually being made, and if the data is as expected in there. That would let you know if it's a problem with your end point or the code.

Comment: jakhicks>This is not the problem. The calls can be separated with 10minutes it will be the same result.

Comment: Problem solved guys thanks for having sepnd time on this non-issue...

Answer (score 0):

that's ok, I just missed the "static" on my class that built my JSON... -> Noob !

Comment: so your server was sending the same data for each request, and this wasn't an issue with angularjs at all?